# My Winforms MaterialSkin.2 tab control is using a lot of space for content

Tags: c#, winforms, material-design

I have a Winforms .Net Framework application with MaterialSkin.2 nuget package installed. The issue is, I have a lot of tabs, and with icons they use 2 rows in the designer. But the pages are then loaded on the left side as expected during runtime. While designing those rows take up a lot of space, and if I want to have a button on the bottom, it is not fully there (images below), also when I want the buttons to be at the far right corner, they overflow. How can i fix this issue. I learned Winforms Material design via Youtube Fox Learn channel. I am using VS2022.

Design image. I set the TabControl dock to fill.

[image: Design]

Runtime image. As you can see the right buttons have overflown, and the bottom ones are not fully down at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Anchor the buttons correctly. `Button2.AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;` - `Button3.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;`....

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but how would I design a full form for an example if i have elements besides one another and have eg. 15 elements on a page

Comment: It depends on how you'd like to lay them out. Maybe [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Maybe with some `Panel` controls. Maybe without any layout container, just with the `Anchor` and/or `Dock` properties. It depends.

Comment: @dr.null do you think i coupd just put a pa el in and dock fill and anchors. And than just display a user control?

Comment: I see a fixed-size Form, not resizable. Right? If so, then keep it simple, just place the controls and anchor and/or dock them properly.

Comment: @dr.null yes the form is not resizable. But how can I then position the elements right in the designer, if I then have to edit the code

Comment: No, you don't need to write any code. Use the designer. I just wrote in my first comment the anchor styles that you need to set. Just add and select a control, switch to the Properties Window, and set the relevant properties.

Comment: @dr.null thank you for your suggestions. The anchoring worked. I still need to practice it, but it did what i wanted. Could you make an answer so I could have the solution saved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control location is relative to its parent. The control needs to know what to do when its parent client size is changed. In a simple design that doesn't utilize the layout panels, the control [`Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and/or [`Dock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties are used for that. The former defines the edges of the container to which a control is bound. The later defines which control borders are *docked* to its parent. Both tell the control how it's resized with its parent.

The buttons in the second screenshot remain in the same position because their Anchor properties are set to the default values. `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left`. What happens here is the [`ClientSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the `TabControl` is changed at runtime. As a result, the space below the bottom buttons is the **Height** of the tabs area when it's top aligned (design time), and the clipped size of the right buttons is the **width** of that area when it's left aligned (runtime).

To run what you design, switch to the Properties Window and set the [`Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties of the buttons as follows:

```cs
Button1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left; // The default.
Button2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left;
Button3.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
Button4.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
```